# Possible to redirect AND show content with Sinatra?

Tags: redirect, sinatra

I'd like to do a redirect with a Sinatra route AND show a redirection message. So

http://api.mysite.com/product/123.html would do this

```
redirect product.url, 301
```

AND output

```
"redirecting..."
```

Is this possible, and what would the code look like?

Comment: respond with `200 Ok` and put the message into the body. put client side redirect (a `meta` tag) after a timeout into the html header.

Comment: Eh. A true 301 redirect feels more solid to me.

Answer (score 0):

From [the Sinatra documentation for `redirect`](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Browser%20Redirect):

> Any additional parameters are handled like arguments passed to `halt`:
>
> ```ruby
> redirect to('/bar'), 303
> redirect 'http://google.com', 'wrong place, buddy'
> ```

and for [`halting`](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Halting):

> You can also specify the status when halting:
>
> ```ruby
> halt 410
> ```
>
> Or the body:
>
> ```ruby
> halt 'this will be the body'
> ```
>
> Or both:
>
> ```ruby
> halt 401, 'go away!'
> ```

So you can do:

```ruby
redirect product.url, 301, "redirecting..."
```

Although the [HTTP spec says](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.2):

> ...the entity of the response SHOULD contain a short hypertext note with a hyperlink to the new URI(s).

so you might want to do:

```ruby
redirect product.url, 301, "redirecting to #{product.url}..."
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately I don't see a message when adding a third argument to the redirect call. I have this: `redirect product.url, 301, 'redirecting to <a href="#{product.url}">#{product.url}</a>...'`

Comment: @ChadJohnson You mean you want the page to load with a delay before redirecting to the new page?

Comment: Well, there is like a one-second delay before it redirects. It's doing a DNS lookup of the target URL or something. I'd like to show a message during that time.