# How to display an error message upon invalid login and route back to username and password screen in ruby sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

What I want to do is to be able to put an error message of my choosing if username/password combo is wrong I can just make another view but want to be able to just go back to login screen instead if having to go to a invalid login view I know there has to be something simple I can add on next line after :login but when i put "This is a sample error message" or something like that it just will display it and not bring me back to login screen.

```
post '/login' do
    authenticate
    if @auth == 1
        erb :main
    else 
        erb :login
    end
end
```

Comment: You can do a [redirect back][1] after displaying the error message. 


  [1]: http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Browser%20Redirect

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you trying but I guess you can solve it with redirects as @barerd suggested

Comment: İ think you should check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18936716/664404. Also, İ think that you will benefit a lot by studying other questions of that poster.

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured out my issue Im not redirecting anymore i added a parameter to my code

```
Post '/login' do authenticate if @auth == 1 erb :main else erb:login,:locals => {:message => "Failed"} end end and

get '/login' do erb :login ,:locals => {:message => "!!Type in your username and password!!"}
```

and in my view file

```
<form action="/login" method="POST">
<input class="login" type="text" name="username" value="Username"><br>
<input class="login" type="password" name="password" value="Password"><br>
<input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit...If you dare">
<form action="/login" method="POST">
<%=message%>

</form>
```